# How can PhoneGap share link?

Tags: jquery-mobile, plugins, cordova, social-networking

I am using PhoneGap to create Mobile Application.
How can I share link to social network that installed in Phone like ( WhatsApp , Messaging ).

regards,

Answer (score 0):

use this plugin, it supports whatsapp as well: https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin